# Opening files in Photoshop with an applescript droplet

Tags: applescript

I have a problem. I am a complete Applescript novice and I am trying to simply open 3 files from my desktop into Photoshop CS4 using a droplet, but when I drop the files I get This error:

Can't get alias "Macintosh HD:Users:nazkav:Desktop:Kav1_jpg"

This is the code I'm using:

```
    on open these_files
      repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_files
        set this_file to item i of these_files
         my image(this_file)
      end repeat
    end open
    on image(the_image)
      tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS4"
        activate
        open the_image as JPEG
      end tell
    end image
```

I hope somebody can help
Thanks in advance

Kavin

Comment: Sorry everyone I've managed to fix this issue. It was just a case of me being a bit stupid Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer and accept it. This will bump the question off the “open” list (this is not only acceptable, but SOP on SO).